# TFS Build Release Automation

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, git-flow, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We are currently using GitFlow as our branching strategy and have automated our build and releases. We have recently initiated the task to further automate our release pipeline by updating associated work items appropriately and send out emails detailing the items that are now available for testing making use of the TFS API. However, the branching strategy is not playing nice with how TFS associated items during their builds.

When we create our release branch off of our develop branch and push it to the server, it links to 'x' amount (didn't count) regardless if a previous release branch off of develop encompassed those items. Is there a way  to force TFS not to see this as a new branch so it assumes everything needs to linked? Instead, it would be nice if we could say this release branch targets these items and only have those show in the association list in the build.

**Note** any subsequent commits for defects works as expected. It's just the initial push after branching off of develop.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

For the Work items linked to associated changes, it will linked all the work items from `develop` branch when you build new created release branches each time. And there is no such setting for VSTS build definition to link only part of work items from `develop` branch when building the new created release branch.

The workaround is **disable Automatically link new work in this build** option in your build definition and **link part of work items you want by a build task** (such as PowerShell task) manually.

[image]